# What are "benign errors"?

Tags: logging

It's been a few weeks since we upgraded to SBS 2011, and I'm trying to keep a good look at the server logs at all times. I'm alarmed however, that I get quite a lot of errors and warnings, so I've been trying to resolve the underlying problems I percieve must cause these alerts.

But it seems some of them aren't really supposed to be fixed? For instance here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2483007, Microsoft seems to recommend not doing anything about quite a few problems,

> **Resolution:** The errors are benign and may be safely ignored.

Is there really such a thing as a benign error? Then why is it reported? I'm concerned that since for instance I have about 10 VSS warnings every hour that are supposedly not really warnings, I will not notice if an error condition acually arises. How do you handle logged errors which cannot be "fixed"?

Comment: Apply a bigger hammer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Benign errors" is a total misnomer: some programmer trying to sound too important. Most of us just call those "warnings" or "notices".

Comment: And then you just ignore them? Do you somehow mask them? I get warning mails every week about having critical errors logged, which I want to, but those that are currently arise are "benign critial errors"

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not enough of a windows geek to give you an exact solution but I suggest looking for some kind of logging level setting. In the unix world there is usually a scale (sometimes 0-10, sometimes labels) that defines how verbose a program should make it's messages and at what level of criticalness to start defining things as errors. Perhaps your SMS has similar functionality.

Comment: In my specific case this is not applicable, but in general this seems to be a good advice. Thanks!